# Auto Increment in pivot not by rows count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a pivot table named `order_user` and I want to set an auto increment in this table, but I want to update this column by each `user_id`, and not by the row count in the table.

Something like this:

```
user_id |order_id|count|
--------|--------|-----|-----
    1   |   2    | 1   |
    2   |   4    | 1   | <---
    5   |   2    | 1   |
    1   |   6    | 2   | <---
        |        |     |
```

I want Laravel or MySQL to do this for me, not by custom query attempt!

Comment: Not something you can do in a query, but something you would do once the query is returned ie. in PHP.

Comment: Could also use a before insert trigger.

Comment: @SloanThrasher , i want mysql do this or laravel , i dont want use my own query!

Comment: @D.Foley i dont want use custom query to do something like this, i want mysql or laravel perform this!

Comment: You can, if you wait me a few minutes I will post the query you need

Comment: I don't know what a 'custom query' is. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry , I don't want get count column and then increment it custom then update the row, i want  some function to do this something like incrementBy()

Comment: It is not clear why count should change from 1 to 2 or what is being pivoted.

Comment: @P.Salmon I want count column be an auto increment column! so it must increase!

Comment: Why does it increase what's the logic?

Comment: @P.Salmon , I want know each user's orders count , i can use queries like count to get this information but i want fully optimized query to do this, in fact i want get daily user's orders count and i don't want search on created_at column, in end of the day I empty the count and it starts again in next day from 0, i want something like this!

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 session variables to control the flow of the query, one to know if your user change and two for counting the orders.
You need to change the table name "orderbyuser"

```
SELECT   
  user_id,
  order_id,
  orderCount
FROM
  (SELECT 
    user_id,
    order_id,
    IF(@userId<>user_id, @countId:=1, @countId:=@countId+1) orderCount,
    @userId:=user_id
  FROM 
    orderbyuser, #change table name
    (SELECT @countId:=0, @userId:=null) c
  ORDER BY
    user_id,
    order_id) data
```

Comment: thanks, but i want optimizer query what is important in this situation for me is performance!

Comment: Better than this on the MySql is a store procedure, or get all data in PHP and number it, this query is speedy, I test in my projects with hundred of thousands of data and worked fine